# How to select non-contiguous files on a Mac?

Tags: macos, finder, selection

How can I select non-contiguous files on a Mac? On Windows I would use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click, but Finder considers this to be a right click.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use ⌘-click (command-click). Most shortcuts in Windows that use CTRL use ⌘ in OS X.

Answer (score 1):

I had same question but we were remote controlling a Mac OSX through VNC with a Windows keyboard so there was no Apple key and the Win key did not work.

However the Alt key on my windows keyboard worked.

Answer (score -1):

The command/Apple/flower key does pretty much the same thing in MacOS that the Ctrl key does in Windows.
Also, Google is your friend: http://www.google.com/search?q=mac+os+select+multiple+files
For details, see this [tech support cheatsheet](http://xkcd.com/627/).

Comment: Why the down vote? At least leave a comment.

Comment: Two downvotes and counting. :(  Still, my original answer wasn't really an answer, so I added one.  I was really just looking for an excuse to post that XKCD cartoon.  Is there a humour tag?  But I'm always a little surprised when people post questions with such easily-found answers.  Maybe this is for meta, but do we want to replace Google as the first stop for computer questions?

Comment: Don't necessarily want to replace Google and you're right that this is an *easy* question, but I know that if I search a computer question at Google and get a link to Superuser, I'll probably get a nicely curated answer rather than an endless thread on a forum with a dubious solution. Again, not necessarily relevant for this question.

Comment: Google links are looked down upon.

Comment: Google links are looked down upon. Also, your "answer" doesn't answer the question. Such stuff is meant for the comment box ( although again Google links are likely to be flagged and removed as spam). If I ahd seen the original answer I'd have downvoted too.